# change color of cell with mouse click

Tags: excel

Excel 2003, I want to change the color of a cell with just a mouse click.  This I have done, my question is how do I get the original color back with a second mouse click on the cell.  I want to be able to change the color of the cell from white to green and back again with each mouse click.

Comment: Pls post your current code (implied with 'This i have done')

Answer (score 3):

This is what I use on one of my sheets. Basically the user double clicks on a cell to bring up a user form; and it highlights the cell yellow when they submit their correction.  If they make a mistake then they double-click to remove the highlight.  You should be able to just pull out the middle of the code below for what you need.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

 Application.EnableEvents = False

    Dim TargRow As Variant
    Dim TargCol As Variant

    TargRow = Target.Row
    TargCol = Target.Column

    Header = 8
    FirstCol = 0
    LastCol = 13
    CommentCol = 13

    If TargRow > Header And TargCol > FirstCol And TargCol < LastCol Then
        'If the cell is clear
        If Target.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone Then
            Cancel = True

            'Then change the background to yellow
            Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
            Corrections.Show

            'Else if the cell background color is already yellow
            ElseIf Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 6 Then

            'Then clear the background
            Target.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
        End If
    End If

    'This is to prevent the cell from being edited when double-clicked
    Cancel = True

    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

EDITED CODE per comments below:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    'If the target cell is clear
    If Target.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone Then

        'Then change the background to the specified color
        Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 4

        'But if the target cell is already the specified color
        ElseIf Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 4 Then

        'Then clear the background color
        Target.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I'm still having problems.  I'm trying to apply this to specif cells.  What I have now is as follows:

Comment: Ok. I chopped down what I have above and changed where to put it. The code is placed as a SelectionChange event on the worksheet. It only requires you to click a cell (not double click like above); clicking the cell turns the cell green - single-clicking the cell again clears the color. Also, the cells can still be edited unlike my original answer above. See edited answer above for code.